# Force multiple users to remove their appcache

Tags: html5-appcache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My HTML5 Application Cache Manifest is caching everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287044/my-html5-application-cache-manifest-is-caching-everything)

I have made an webapp that could be cached, however the cache created a lot of problems, so I need them all to clear their cache.

Can this be done automatically on my server?

Would any these options work?

- change `<html manifest="cache.appcache">` to `<html>`
- remove the `cache.appcache` file from the server
- add `NETWORK:` title above all resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaying on the specification the first two options should do the work. because when the manifest is not reachable a browser should remove all cached data.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817490/1482507