# appcache served as text/plain only works in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-appcache

I'm working on an application that has a broken manifest file. It's broken in a bunch of ways.

One of the ways that it's broken is that it is being served as type `text/plain`.

Safari and Firefox ignore it because of this. None of Safari, Firefox, or Chrome show the manifest file being downloaded in firebug/inspector. Safari does show an error in its console about the incorrect mime type.

Only Chrome accepts the manifest file and creates an application cache. (This, of course, causes the application to break horribly, because the manifest's contents are wrong...)

I was under the impression that any manifest served with an incorrect mime type would be ignored.

**Should manifests served as mime type `text/plain` be ignored? Is this a known bug in Chrome?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#writing-cache-manifests) a manifest must be served with mime-type `text/cache-manifest`.

If a browser interprets a manifest without that mime-type just because it was referenced in `<html manifest="xxx">` it's not following the specification for 100%. But in my opinion: that's not a bug, it's a feature! :D

---

Aside that, why referencing a manifest without the correct mime-type anyway (instead of not referencing one at all)?

> This, of course, causes the application to break horribly, because the manifest's contents are wrong...

Reading that I would assume that you just want to clean the appcache of Users already loaded the missconfigured manifest? If that's your intention so try it on the way described there: [Removing HTML5 Appcache Manifest, Permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815280/removing-html5-appcache-manifest-permanently?rq=1)