# Clear appcahe programmatically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, offline-caching

In my application I am using html5 offline caching. I need to clear the appcache programmatically after user sign out (Because the view of the page differs with respect to user role). Is there any way to do this progammatically?
I have tried with "updateready" event.

```
$(this.applicationCache).bind("updateready", function() {
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
    window.location.reload();
});
```

But this is not seems to be a good solution because triggering the "updateready" event takes some time.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653871/programmatically-clear-html-5-application-cache-in-log-on-log-off-scenario

Comment: you can put the per-user data in a different url under the network: section.